Does the Torah imply that the heart leads to sin more than the eyes?
The third paragraph of the Shema taken from Numbers 15:39 states,

וְהָיָ֣ה לָכֶם֮ לְצִיצִת֒ וּרְאִיתֶ֣ם אֹת֗וֹ וּזְכַרְתֶּם֙
אֶת־כׇּל־מִצְוֺ֣ת יְהֹוָ֔ה וַעֲשִׂיתֶ֖ם אֹתָ֑ם וְלֹֽא־תָת֜וּרוּ
אַחֲרֵ֤י לְבַבְכֶם֙ וְאַחֲרֵ֣י עֵֽינֵיכֶ֔ם אֲשֶׁר־אַתֶּ֥ם זֹנִ֖ים
אַחֲרֵיהֶֽם׃
That shall be your fringe; look at it and recall all the commandments
of יהוה and observe them, so that you do not follow your heart and
eyes in your lustful urge.

From the order of the words it seems that the Torah is implying that one is more likely to stray after his heart than his eyes. Is this really true? It seems to me, from Svara and personal experience, that the initiator to do an aveira is the eyes and the urge is carried through with the heart, so shouldn’t it be the other way around. I.e do not follow your eyes and heart in your lustful urge
Does anyone know of any Rishonim or Achronim that discuss this question or similar from another context?
Thank you

https://parashat.co.il/%D7%94%D7%A2%D7%99%D7%99%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%9D-%D7%95%D7%94%D7%9C%D7%91/

https://www.hidabroot.org/article/1171904

https://midrasha.biu.ac.il/node/2526

@shmosel thank you very much, all three answered the question with different sources which was very nice! It would very beneficial if we can summarize the main points to form an answer here so other people can benefit from this teaching as well in English on this platform

I'm sure I've answered this exact question here somewhere
